# Not all questions are listed in the "faq" ordering on a Questions/List page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, question-lists

For example:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-software-engineering?sort=faq&pagesize=50 = 10 questions
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-software-engineering?sort=newest&pagesize=50 = 55 questions
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/stci-software-engineering/info = 55 questions
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stci-software-engineering?sort=votes = 55 questions

"FAQ" is described in the hover text as "questions with the most links", but I interpret that as an ordering, not a filtering. That interpretation is consistant with the hover text for the other links (votes -> "questions with the most votes" -> sorted with most net upvotes on the top, and even that is vague since the hover text should probably be "highest rated questions").

At least, for consistency, even without a wording change, "faq" should still display all of the questions, just sorted differently.

Comment: ("newest" is actually the default tab when you click on a tag; the site was just remembering you were on the faq tab before and carrying that preference over. This is unrelated to your primary focus here, though)

Comment: @TimStone Interesting. That's also somewhat annoying, but it appears you are correct.

Comment: With the first link you report, I see 55 questions, not 10.

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's because of what Tim Stone reported. You need to explicitly go to the FAQ link.

Answer (score 2):

We felt that the FAQ tab should work in an exclusionary fashion - questions that have links or are linked to are listed, while those without are not.  Same as bounty.

There really couldn't be a clear delineation of those with and without links if all questions were listed.

Comment: Could this be made more obvious by adjusting the hover text and/or "n questions tagged" text on the different tabs to make it clear that newest, votes, and active are sorts and faq and unanswered are filters? Since it is intentional, it isn't clear that the intent is for some to sort and others to filter.